# DC Generator with magnet as rotor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

DC generators convert the AC current in them by split ring commutators right and the graph of the current will be like this
[image]

but the question is how would be the graph if the magnet is the rotor and not the armature? Me and a part of my friends are on the opinion that the the graph will be like this and a few of my friends say that it will be like the usual

[image]

I would like to know how it would be

Comment: Yes is correct. The rotation of the armature commutes the connection to the circuit so current in the circuit flows in the same direction regardless of the direction in the armature. If the armature is fixed, it will only couple to the circuit in a unique way, and the circuit will experience the current in the same sense as the armature, which is the way you are showing below.

Comment: Unless, of course, there is still a commutation brush set on the rotor which acts as a mechanical rectifier - but that would make the design unnecessarily complex...

Comment: @Floris there is nothing like that the arrangements are split ring commutator and brush. When the armature becomes the stator the contact with the commutator and brush doesn't change right that's the conclusion that i have finally arrived at

Comment: @Akshay when the windings don't move you usually don't even have the need for brushes - the dynamo used for lights on a bicycle is often like that (I know - I took one apart as a kid). No sliding contacts = more reliable. Your waveform is right.

Comment: @Floris Great so i was right now i can print screen these answers to show it to my friends

Comment: Essentially - when the magnet is rotating and the coils are stationary, you have an AC generator unless you play tricks with brushes. This is because the _net_ flux change in the coil after a complete revolution is necessarily zero - and thus the _net_ voltage must be zero too.

Comment: @Floris  you  should post this as an answer (not as a comment)

Comment: @rmhleo you should post this as an answer (not as a comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes is correct. The rotation of the armature commutes the connection to the circuit so current in the circuit flows in the same direction regardless of the direction in the armature. If the armature is fixed, it will only couple to the circuit in a unique way, and the circuit will experience the current in the same sense as the armature, which is the way you are showing below.

Answer (score 1):

When the magnet is rotating and the coils are stationary, you have an AC generator unless you play tricks with brushes. This is because the net flux change in the coil after a complete revolution is necessarily zero - and thus the net voltage must be zero too.

The sinusoidal waveform in your second sketch is therefore what you expect to see in a brushless generator with rotating magnet. You are right.